# How can I quickly access my music from the desktop?

Tags: directory

Any suggestions on how can I play music files directly from the desktop without opening file manager?

For example: In Windows, I can do it by adding a directory toolbar to the taskbar.

Comment: That ubuntuforums link requires a login for me to view it. Can you copy the image and put it in your post, instead of a link?

Answer (score 1):

Banshee gives you one-click access to your playlists, like this:

[image: banshee from the sound menu]

Note that Banshee has to already be running to see this option.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any direct equivalents, but you can search your music collection using the Music Lens in the Unity Dash.

1. Enter the Dash by clicking on the Ubuntu logo at the top of the Unity Launcher (in the top left).
2. Click on the small picture of the musical notes at the bottom of the Dash:

You will notice that clicking on the **Filter results** option will reveal a number of options to narrow your search.

Note: You must have imported your music collection into Banshee for this to work.